# Replace the data deleting the old data

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am using Android Studio and i am reading the data continuously from the bluetooth device and i am appending it. But instead of appending,i would like to replace the data with the new data that has been received. I am using a text view to display the data. Pls suggest some ideas.

This is the code i have written:

```
bt.setOnDataReceivedListener(new OnDataReceivedListener() 
{
        public void onDataReceived(byte[] data, String message) 
        {
        textRead.append(message + "\n");
        }
});
```

Comment: what is the type of `textRead`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
textRead.setText(message);
```

Comment: Yes. It Worked. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: glad that it helped :)